# Can I make asyncio.sleep() wait for only 1 person?

Tags: python

I'm making a currency simulator, and I want to use asyncio.sleep() to have a delay before adding any more money to an account. The problem is, that multiple people will be using this at the **same time**, so I need a way to make it pause only for 1 person. Here is my code more or less:

```
time = True

if not time:
   print("wait more")
   return

# add money and stuff here

time = False
await asyncio.sleep(10.0)
time = True
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be something like:

```
class character:
...
    def startPause(self,pause=10)# pause  is how long the pause will be and is at default set to 10
        self.startTime = time.time()
        self.pauseTime = pause



    def add_money(self):
        if time.time-self.startTime>self.pauseTime:
            print("wait more")
        ...
```

What this program does is by calling the startPause function it sets a startTime. Unless startTime-time.time is greater than how long the pause is it will break/discontinue the function.